# How to split a string in two by first digit occurrence?

Tags: javascript, regex, split, substring

Having a string like this

```
str = "word 12 otherword(s) 2000 19"
```

or like this

```
str = "word word 12 otherword(s) 2000 19"
```

I need to split the string in two, in order to have an array like this:

`newstr[0] = first part of the string` (i.e. "word" in the first case, "word word" in the second case);

`newstr[1] = rest of the string` (i.e. "12 otherword(s) 2000 19" in both cases).

I've tried to accomplish this using `split` and `regex`, without success:

`str.split(/\d.*/)` returns `Array [ "word ", "" ]` or `Array [ "word word ", "" ]`

while `str.split(/^\D*/gm)` returns `Array [ "", "12 otherword(s) 2000 19" ]`

Would you give me a suggestion? Even without using `split` and `regex` - if there's a better/faster (Vanilla JavaScript) solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's 3 things going on here.

1. String.split usually doesn't includes the matched delimiter in the return array. So splitting `abc.split('b')` would return `['a', 'c']`. This behavior can be changed by using a matching regex group; i.e. adding parens `'abc'.split(/(b)/)` will return `['a', 'b', 'c']`.
2. String.split will keep the delimter seperate from the other elements. I.e. `'abc'.split(/(b)/)` will return 3 elements `['a', 'b', 'c']`. Suffix the regex with `.*` to combine the last 2 elements: `'abc'.split(/(b.*)/)` will return `['a', 'bc', '']`.
3. Lastly, to ignore the last empty element, we send the 2nd param of `2`.

```js
let str = "word word 12 otherword(s) 2000 19";
let splitStr = str.split(/(\d.*)/, 2);
console.log(splitStr);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can match these parts:

```js
const strs = ["word 12 otherword(s) 2000 19", "word word 12 otherword(s) 2000 19"];
for (var s of strs) {
  const [_, part1, part2] = s.match(/^(\D*)(\d+[\w\W]*)/)
  console.log([part1, part2])
}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ITVDyT/1).

*Regex details*:

- `^` - start of a string
- `(\D*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than digits
- `(\d+[\w\W]*)` - Group 2: one or more digits, and then any zero or more chars as many as possible.

Note you may `.trim()` the resulting parts when using them (print them with `console.log([part1.trim(), part2.trim()])`).